# which criteria decides what goes in an Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular

I am facing sometimes issues to decide what goes on a given component. In some cases we can have two different UI elements that share the same data and it makes sens to put them in one component even if it's not the case semantically just to have less data sharing overhead (custom events...). Which criteria decides how to design the component tree of an Angular 2 project?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm wrong about this, but I think it is entirely up to your discretion as to how much you'd like to compartmentalize your components and functionality.

For example, suppose I'm writing an application that has users entering data on a series of forms.  I may have the users entering 'address type' information in multiple places.  The addresses may in fact have nothing to do with each other and may not be related at all, but if I find myself reusing the same basic template and the functionality for communicating with services behind it, maybe it's time to wrap these together as an address component that I can inject into parent form components.

This may introduce some initial complexity, as you have to deal with communicating between components and relaying contextual (is this what you mean by 'semantic') information to your child component.

Comment: I guess that angular 2 Style guide avoid to define such best practices to give more flexibility to framework users